# String limitation with matches method in java

Tags: java, regex, string, if-statement, char

I want my String be like "09DD-DDD-DD DD", how should I code this with matches method in java?
this is part of my code but doesn't work:

```
public void setPhone(String p) {
    if (p.charAt(0) == '0' && p.charAt(1) == '9' && p.matches("//d{4}-//d{3}-//d{2} //d{2}")){
        this.phone = p;}
    else System.out.println("phone number must be started with 09 and DDDD-DDD-DD DD");

}
```

Comment: If you want the first two digits to be "09" then you can't use `//d{4}`. Also, you're not escaping the regex correctly since you must use backslashes: \\

Comment: Please be more specific when you say "doesn't work". Always explain what it should have done and what it does instead. As the others said, the problem here is that you are using forward slashes rather than backward slashes. I'll be voting to close this as a typo.

Comment: Your log message would be more helpful if it included `p`.

Answer (score 1):

From what you said, this should be it: `"09\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{2} \\d{2}"`

Comment: Didn't you mean `\\d` instead of `/d`?

Answer (score 0):

Use regex like this:

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ma82J6/1/)

```
^09\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2} \d{2}$
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem is to accept phone numbers. So it should have the regex as:

```
09[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}
```

And your code should look like :

```
if (p.matches("09[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}"){
        phone = p;
}else { 
    System.out.println("phone number must be started with 09 and DDDD-DDD-DD DD");
}
```